# Rewriting quadratic optimization problem with negative definite matrix

Tags: convex-optimization, quadratic-programming, semidefinite-programming

Consider the following problem:

Minimize $x(1-x) + y(1-y) + z(1-z)$ subject to:
$$ a. 0\leq x, y, z \leq 1$$
$$ b. x+y+z = 1$$

If I plug in this problem in a standard quadratic optimizer, which minimizes $\displaystyle c^T \cdot \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\z \end{pmatrix} + \frac{1}{2}\cdot \begin{pmatrix} x&y&z \end{pmatrix} G \cdot \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\z \end{pmatrix} $, subject to constraints a) and b),  I get the error message "the matrix G is not positive definite".

I'm aware that the minimum is obtained when exactly one of $x, y, z$ is equal to 1 ( and the others 0 ), but I need to translate this problem into a quadratic form with a positive definite matrix $G$ ( as part of a larger problem I am trying to solve, which contains more variables). Are there any suggestions on how to do so? Thanks a lot!

By the way, I am looking for ANY solution, not all solutions to such a problem.

Comment: The objective function is $e^Tv-v^TIv$ where $e=(1,1,1)^T$ and $v=(x,y,z)^T$.

Comment: Yes, and in the standard quadratic form $e^T v + \frac{1}{2} v^T G v$, the matrix $ G = -2I$ is not positive definite in our case, which is a problem. Any ideas on how to put it in a standard quadratic form, or are there any optimization packages that deal with negative definite matrices?